# Conditional lookup in Excel with date as condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: What is the formula I can use to populate the correct result in =? please. Left table is raw data and right table is what I need to populate. Thank you in advance for your help!]

What is the formula I can use to populate the correct result in =? please. Left table is raw data and right table is what I need to populate. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: How does the date relate?

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly your question then you could try:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `H4`

```
=FILTER($E$4:$E$8,($D$4:$D$8=MAXIFS($D$4:$D$8,$B$4:$B$8,G4,$C$4:$C$8,"IN"))*($C$4:$C$8="IN"))
```

---

Or, You could use this as well,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `H4`

```
=TAKE(SORT(FILTER(B4:E8,(G4=B4:B8)*(C4:C8="IN")),3,-1),1,-1)
```

---

Not sure about your **Excel Version**, If you are not using `MS365` then you could use this one works from **Excel 2010+** onwards, also I must give credit for the following solution to **[Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner)** Sir, since sir has posted a solution with `Nested AGGREGATE()` function sometime ago & learnt from there.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `I4`

```
=AGGREGATE(14,7,($E$4:$E$8)/($D$4:$D$8=
AGGREGATE(14,7,($D$4:$D$8)/((G4=$B$4:$B$8)*($C$4:$C$8="IN")),1)),1)
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Use nested MAXIFS:

```
=MAXIFS(D:D,C:C,MAXIFS(C:C,A:A,F2,B:B,"in"),A:A,F2,B:B,"in")
```

[image]